# Reduce a Value from Each Iteration of Foreach in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to redeem a value from the array. For example I have `20 Points` and I am going to redeem from the list of earned points.

Here is my array structure which will shown as follows

```
$newstructure = array(
array('earnedpoints'=>'10','usedpoints'=>'0'),
array('earnedpoints'=>'25','usedpoints'=>'0'),
);
```

which has `n` number of data's(array).

I am trying to reduce the values from the earned points

`Points to redeem : 20`. In a foreach statement i am just

```
$remainingpoints=20; // Redeeming Points is named as in variable of $remainingpoints
foreach ($newstructure as $keys => $newone) {

        if ($remainingpoints > $newone['earnedpoint']) {

            $remainingpoints = $remainingpoints - $newone['earnedpoint'];

        } else {
            $remainingpoints = $newone['earnedpoint'] - $remainingpoints;

        }


}
```

For the Point Redeeming for the first iteration of foreach earned point is `10`, remaining point is 10 (based on above code) and used point is `10`

For the second iteration the earned point is 25 but i want to redeem only 10 so i want to stop the loop once the redeeming values are finished (Previous Iteration `10` and Current Iteration `10`)

I trying to get the result as (`Redeem Point 20`)

```
First Iteration Used Points 10 and Remaining Points is 10.
Second Iteration Used Points 10 and Remaining Points is 0.
```

Also I am trying to store the information as in the form of array too.

```
 $newstructure = array(
    array('earnedpoints'=>'10','usedpoints'=>'10','remainingpoints'=>'10'),
    array('earnedpoints'=>'25','usedpoints'=>'10','remainingpoints'=>'0'),
    );
```

Can anyone point me a right direction inorder to get this desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, in one place you use `earnedpoints` as your table key, and in loop you use `earnedpoint`.

This code should work for you:

```
<?php


$newstructure = array(
array('earnedpoints'=>'10','usedpoints'=>'0'),
array('earnedpoints'=>'25','usedpoints'=>'0'),
);


$remainingpoints=25; // Redeeming Points is named as in variable of $remainingpoints
foreach ($newstructure as $keys => $newone) {

        if ($remainingpoints  > $newone['earnedpoints']) {
            $toRedeem = $newone['earnedpoints'];            
        }
        else {
            $toRedeem =  $remainingpoints;
        }

        $remainingpoints -= $toRedeem; 

        $newstructure[$keys]['usedpoints'] = $toRedeem;
        $newstructure[$keys]['remainingpoints'] = $remainingpoints;

        /*
        if ( $remainingpoints == 0 ) {
            break;
        }
        */
}


var_dump($newstructure);
```

In comment I put code where you could break your loop but when you break it, you won't have set `used_points` and `remainingpoints` for the following array values

Comment: One more suggestion can you help me?

Comment: It depends, if it's not very related, simple ask another question

Comment: I am trying additional one key which contain expiry for example i set the expiry for each earned points. If i earned points is 20 which is expired in today. 10 Points i already used then another 10 points is going to expire so i want to move that points to expiry is that possible

Comment: You need to create another question I am afraid and explain in details what you want to achieve